# delete line from json file with sed in a shell

Tags: json, bash, sed

I would like to delete a line containing `"electron-inspector": "0.1.4",` from .package.json

The following is not working.

`sed -i '' -e 'electron-inspector' ./package.json`

What do I have to change?

Comment: Don't use sed but a real JSON parser, check my post

Comment: If you removed "from JSON file" from the question, answers that use only `sed` might be acceptable. However -- `sed` *cannot* parse JSON; it cannot ensure that its answer results in a parsable, semantically-correct output document. Since our goal here on StackOverflow is to build a knowledgebase of canonical, correct answers, an approach with serious known bugs when used for the purpose described in the question is hard to countenance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this, but **[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) in not a JSON parser !** [image: warning]

```
sed -i '' -e '/electron-inspector/d' file
```

(`-i ''` is required for macOS's sed)

Imagine a simple (*inline*) case like this :

```
{"foo": 123, "electron-inspector": "0.1.4", "bar": 42 }
```

**BOOOM !**  So :

### The proper way, using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```
jq -r 'del(.["electron-inspector"])' file.json > _.json && mv _.json file.json
```

The dash `-` is a [special case for jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/38)

If instead you had a simple case, the command would be :

```
jq 'del(.electroninspector)' file.json
```

---

Check [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

---

### Another solution using [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and... [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) :

```
cat file.json
{"foo": 123, "electron-inspector": "0.1.4", "bar": 42 }
```

#### Code :

```
$ node<<EOF > _.json && mv _.json file.json                                               
var o = $(< file.json);
delete o["electron-inspector"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(o, null, 4));
EOF
```

#### Edited file :

```
{
    "foo": 123,
    "bar": 42
}
```

---

### Last but not least, to edit the file properly using `sponge` :

Instead of :  `> x.json && mv x.json file.json`, we can do :

```
command ...... file.json | sponge file.json
```

You need [moreutils](/questions/tagged/moreutils) installed.

Comment: Actually, `.electron_inspector` is the special case. `.[x]` works for *any* valid key `x`, while `.x` only works for a subset of valid keys.

Comment: BTW, `-i''` is equivalent to just `-i` with nothing after it; thus, it works with GNU `sed`, but not the BSD implementation (as it leads to the `-e` in the next argument being treated as the extension to use.

Comment: This is from OP question, assuming OP use MacOS. That's the way to go with MacOS

Comment: @GillesQuenot, `-i''` without the space does not work on MacOS; it literally passes the exact same argument vector to `sed` that just `sed -i -e ...` does. It needs to be `-i ''`. Run with `set -x` and compare the trace of running `sed -i''` with that of running `sed -i`, and you'll see they're identical.

Answer (score -3):

I got it to work with:

`sed -i '/electron-inspector/d' package.json`